# ASCII and Unicode difference

Tags: ascii

[I was an undergrad student when I asked this question :P]

why is it important to know the difference between ASCII and Unicode character set?

I learned that ASCII is for 8bit byte character set and Unicode's current ver 6.3 has 1 million codes out of which 0.1 are assigned to characters.

But what is the importance of knowing the difference?

I specified character-set only during JSON parsing or a website's metadata specification without knowing its true significance.

Comment: I use unicode for encoding because I can easily switch between characters and integers just by encoding said integer into a hex value then to unicode. 

I don't know if you can do the same with ASCII, maybe you can, who knows. If not, then that's one reason O:) "encryption" and "encoding" can be done in integer math instead of arrays of ASCII characters.

Comment: Similar to metric vs English units of measure, you needn't know the difference, just use the one you need. (And, it's very unlikely that it will be ASCII. Even when programming in assembly for MS-DOS, you don't use it. Windows doesn't. Most C libraries don't; HTML doesn't. Java doesn't. .NET doesn't. ….)

Comment: "It's not that hard"—[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), but if you have questions after reading, ask away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is defined as a 7-bit code, with values up to to 0x7F. ASCII is a strict subset of one of the Unicode character blocks.

Unicode can be used to encode many different characters in many different writing systems, with millions of defined characters. It is often represented with a variable length encoding. UTF-8 is the most popular encoding for western languages.

By design, ASCII is already encoded as UTF-8, so marking a piece of ASCII text as UTF-8 will cause no issues.

Warning: Many people confuse ASCII with the many "Extended ASCII" character sets that use character values greater than 127. Extended ASCII is NOT UTF-8.